# Can't connect to a supevisor-socket in Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, supervisord

I have a Docker-setup with nginx and my Flask-application (app-container). The nginx-container doesn't have anything special in it. The app-container holds my Flask-application, uWSGI and Supervisor. This container shares the volume that the uWSIG-socket is in so the nginx-container can use the socket. This works as intended, however, I can't access the web interface for Supervisor through nginx. I can't find anything relative to this on Google so I was hoping you guys could help me.

Here's my config files:

**docker-compose**

```
app:
  restart: always
  build: ./app
  command: supervisord -c /www-botillsammans-conf/supervisord.ini
  volumes:
    - '/www-botillsammans-conf'

nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx
  command: nginx -c /www-botillsammans-nginx/nginx.conf
  ports:
    - '80:80'
    - '443:443'
  volumes_from:
    - 'app'
```

**nginx**

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

upstream flask {
    server unix:/www-botillsammans-conf/www.uwsgi.sock;
}

upstream supervisor {
    server unix:/tmp/supervisor.sock;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name botillsammans.nu www.botillsammans.nu;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/ssl_botillsammans.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/ssl_botillsammans.error.log;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # Disable SSLv3
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # Fix Diffie-Hellman for TLS
    # More info: https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_dhparam /www-botillsammans-nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    ## verify chain of trust of OCSP response using Root CA and Intermediate certs
    ssl_trusted_certificate chain1.pem;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=86400;
    resolver_timeout 10;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass flask;
        include uwsgi_params;
        proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token xADstXQmfnMxFZn6SXTq;
    }

    location /supervisor {
        proxy_pass https://supervisor;
    }

    location /supervisor2 {
        proxy_pass http://supervisor;
    }
}
```

**supervisors conf**
    [unix_http_server]
    file = /tmp/supervisor.sock
    chmod = 0777
    chown = 1001:500

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon = true
pidfile = /tmp/supervisord.pid
logfile = /var/log/supervisor/supervisor.log
logfile_maxbytes = 10MB

[supervisorctl]
serverurl = unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock
username = supervisor
password = pass

[program:www]
user = supervisor
command = uwsgi --thunder-lock --ini /www-botillsammans-conf/www.uwsgi.ini
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/www.out.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/www.err.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 10MB
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 10MB
exitcodes = 0
stopsignal = HUP
```

I think that's all the relative configurations. So, my question is really how to make supervisor work with nginx via a UNIX-socket?

Comment: It looks like your supervisor socket file is in `/tmp/supervisor.sock` in your app container which isn't in the volume that you've defined. Try moving your supervisor socket by adding `file = /www-botillsammans-conf/supervisor.sock` to your [supervisord] directive, and then change your nginx config to point here instead of /tmp.

Comment: Well.. That was a dumb mistake, had it in www-botillsammans-conf before but it didn't work then either because of permission errors. I tried to move it back and set the correct permissions but I still get 502 from Nginx on the /supervisor-route and 404 on the /supervisor2-route. Is there any way to log anything from `supervisorctl` or `unix_http_server`?

Comment: Some progress! Managed to get the login-popup, signed in successfully with the username and password from the config-files but when I got signed in I got to a 404-page with `Message: Not Found.`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

I ended up doing a subdomain for supervisor, read somewhere that supervisor and nginx didn't work very well together if supervisor didn't its own subdomain. So here's my config-files now:

**nginx (the supervisor subdomain)**

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}

upstream supervisor {
  server unix:/conf/supervisor.sock;
}

# HTTP redirect
server {
  listen 80;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name supervisor.example.com;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/supervisor.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/supervisor.error.log;

  server_tokens off;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/supervisor/fullchain1.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/supervisor/privkey1.pem;

  ssl_session_timeout 1d;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_tickets off;

  # Disable SSLv3
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  # Fix Diffie-Hellman for TLS
  # More info: https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/dhparams.pem;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;

  ## verify chain of trust of OCSP response using Root CA and Intermediate certs
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/supervisor/chain1.pem;
  resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=86400;
  resolver_timeout 10;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    # hack the host https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/251
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host/supervisor/index.html;
    proxy_redirect off;
    rewrite ^/supervisor(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://supervisor;
  }
}
```

**supervisord.ini**

```
[unix_http_server]
file = /conf/supervisor.sock
chmod = 0770
chown = 1001:500
username = user
password = password

[supervisord]
nodaemon = true
pidfile = /conf/supervisor.pid
logfile = /var/log/supervisor/supervisor.log
childlogdir = /var/log/supervisor/
loglevel = debug
logfile_maxbytes = 10MB

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl = unix:///conf/supervisor.sock
historyfile = /var/log/supervisor/historyfile

[program:www]
user = supervisor
command = uwsgi --thunder-lock --ini /conf/www.uwsgi.ini
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/www.out.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/www.err.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 10MB
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 10MB
exitcodes = 0
stopsignal = HUP
```